# XPath syntax for searching generic text?

Tags: ruby, parsing, xpath, nokogiri

I have an HTML page that I parse using Nokogiri, and I should find generic text contained in every element. It doesn't matter which element it is, it just should match the text I pass to `contains()`.

The results I'm able to get at the moment are very generic and I'm not sure I'm interpreting the XPath documentation correctly:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(page['result'])
puts html.xpath("/*[contains(., 'Foobar')]")
```

What I would like is the element that contains "Foobar", but the library is returning the whole page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `//*[contains(child::text(), 'Foobar')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `/` with an XPath means start at the root of the document, which isn't what you want. `xpath` will find all matching elements, which means all ancestor nodes of the one containing the text you want will also be found, resulting in everything below the root meeting the condition.

Here's an example showing this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<html><body><div><p>foobar</p></div></body></html>'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.xpath("/*[contains(., 'foobar')]").map(&:to_html)
# => ["<html><body><div><p>foobar</p></div></body></html>"]
```

I'd search for it this way:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<html><body><div><p id="1">foobar</p></div><div><p id="2">foobar</p></div></body></html>'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.search("//text()[contains(., 'foobar')]").map{ |t| t.parent.to_html }
# => ["<p id=\"1\">foobar</p>", "<p id=\"2\">foobar</p>"]
```

This searches all text nodes for the text you want, then retrieves the parent of that node which seems more useful.

Here's the same code tweaked to retrieve the XPath to the node:

```
doc.search("//text()[contains(., 'foobar')]").map{ |t| t.parent.path }
# => ["/html/body/div[1]/p", "/html/body/div[2]/p"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath you tried return all elements containing `Foobar` text *including ancestor* of those mentioned elements (because the ancestors is also considered containing `Foobar` text, despite *indirectly*).

You can do this way to get only elements that *directly* containing `Foobar` text :

```
puts html.xpath("/*[contains(text(), 'Foobar')]")
```